# Dictionary that doesn't exist returning name of string, how to skip this Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that holds different value and id's.
The first index in the dictionary does not hold the 'id' dictionary, but the second index does
The problem I am having is when I print:

`return[0]['values']['id']`

It returns
`'id'`

Because there is no such dictionary in the first index

The second index
`return[1]['values']['id']`
The 'id' dictionary does exist so returns
`[{"id": "4651234", "type":"instant"}]`

I'm trying to create a list of only the id values that exist, how do I get it to skip the all the indexes where the 'id' dictionary does not exist? Rather than stop the program and print the string 'id'.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are asking why your code doesn’t retrieve the expected value from a dictionary. *But you haven't shown us the dictionary.* We can't guess. Please [edit] your question to show us the dictionary, or (if it is big) a small piece of it that still exhibits the behaviour you don't expect.

Comment: I’m very surprised, because in a dict, if you try to query a missing value, it will raise a `KeyError`. This is not supposed to send the key if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop and  use a if statement to check if the id exists or not :

```py
id_list = []
for key in return:
    if return[key]['values']['id'] != 'id':
        id_list.append(return[key]['values']['id'])
```

(Btw you should avoid naming your variables with name like return or any other keyword that can have a signification for the language)

Comment: You even don't have to use `!= 'id'` in condition, as empty entries will be evaluated to `Falsy`

Comment: Hi when this runs if return[0]['values']['id'] it doesn't even evaluate the if statement it just returns 'id'

Answer (score 0):

you can if the returned value it is a list or a string

```
if isinstance(return[0]['values']['id'],list):
   #process the data
elif isinstance(return[0]['values']['id'],str):
   #do nothing
```

Having said that, a couple of recommendations: I assume that you wrote it as an example but, just in case, is not possible to have "return" as the name of the variable since it is a reserved word.

Another point is that if the same call returns different things (i.e. the first returns a str, the second a list with a dictionary in it, etc), it may be an indication that the data needs some cleaning before trying to access it. Otherwise you may end up with nasty results and you won't know where they are coming from.

Comment: Hi thanks very much for the reply,Yes just being used as an example there's a weird issue where even the if statement return[0]['values']['id'] just returns 'id', even if i store it in a variable it prints the string 'id'